# Firebug Double console.log messages

Tags: firebug

I'm creating a class to create and delete folders and some other things I still have to work on. I'm doing this via ajax. And it works fine. But I get the same message in the console twice.

Why is that?  Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code till now (also available at http://snippi.com/s/3sfsfvm):

```
<?php

//process.php

if(!empty($_POST['foldddername'])) {

    require_once 'test.php';
    $folder = new folder;

    $path = dirname( __FILE__ );

    $foldername = strip_tags($_POST['foldddername']);

//  $folder ->crtFolder($foldername,$path);
    if($message = $folder ->crtFolder($foldername,$path)) {
        echo $message;
    }
}


?>

    <?php

//test.php

class folder
{

    public function crtFolder($foldername,$path){
        $dirpath = $path."\\".$foldername;

        if ((!is_dir($dirpath))) {
            if(mkdir($dirpath,0777,true)) {
                $error = false;
                $message['error'] = false;
                $message['message'] = "Folder Created";
                return json_encode($message);
            }
                else { 
                    $error = true;
                    $message['error'] = true;
                    $message['message'] = "Folder Failed To Create";
                    return json_encode($message); 
                }
        }
            else {
                $error = true;
                $message['error'] = true;
                $message['message'] = "Folder Already Exists";
                return json_encode($message);   
            }

    }
}


?> 



    //Ajax handling

$(function(){
$('.submittt').click(function(){
        if($('input.folder-name').val() == "")
        {
            console.log('Please enter Folder Name');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {           
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:
                {
                    foldddername: $('input.folder-name').val()
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data.message);
                    if(data.error === true)
                    {
                        console.log(data.message);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        console.log(data.message);

                    }
                },
                error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)
                {
                    console.log(data.message);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this part of code produces duplicates:

```
success:function(data) {
    console.log(data.message);  # 1st time
    if(data.error === true) {
    console.log(data.message);  # duplicate
}
else {
    console.log(data.message);  # duplicate
    }
},
```

Comment: Yes, I now have seen the problem, if you haven't told me that it was just my doing I would have thought that it was some other bigger problem Thank you :)